# ON UNION ALL, shows two search results

Tags: mysql

```
enter SELECT id
 , stock
 , nombre
 , CONCAT(descuento, '%') AS descuento
 , CONCAT('$', FORMAT(precio, 2)) AS precio
 , CONCAT('$', FORMAT(total, 2)) AS total
 , tipo
 FROM producto
 WHERE stock >= 1
  AND visto IS NULL
   AND nombre LIKE 'materna%'
UNION ALL
SELECT id
     , '' AS 'stock'
     , nombre
     , CONCAT('$', FORMAT(descuento, 2)) AS descuento
     , CONCAT('$', FORMAT(precio, 2)) AS precio
     , CONCAT('$', FORMAT(total, 2)) AS total
     , tipo 
  FROM servicio AS s 
 WHERE visto IS NULL
   AND nombre LIKE 'materna%'
```

; here

[picture example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVzMI.png)

It shows a result that does not correspond

Thanks

Comment: You need to actually ask a question here. There are no mind readers out here in stack space.

Comment: FROM servicio AS s WHERE visto IS Null AND nombre LIKE '%materna%'

Comment: "does not correspond" ... to *what*? The resultset returned looks to be a reasonable return for the query. What *exactly* is the problem with the resultset? Were you expecting more rows? Only one row? Or zero rows? This post is more a report of current status (thanks for sharing?) There is no *question* that can be answered.

Comment: the result of "materna" expected single row, but shows another row with unlike name "materna".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try using `LIKE` with the wildcard character `%`. Consider `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` to omit duplicate rows. See live example here: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8531a6/1/0).

```
SELECT id
     , stock
     , nombre
     , CONCAT(descuento, '%') AS descuento
     , CONCAT('$', FORMAT(precio, 2)) AS precio
     , CONCAT('$', FORMAT(total, 2)) AS total
     , tipo
  FROM producto
 WHERE stock >= 1
  AND visto IS NULL
   AND nombre LIKE 'materna%'
UNION
SELECT id
     , '' AS 'stock'
     , nombre
     , CONCAT('$', FORMAT(descuento, 2)) AS descuento
     , CONCAT('$', FORMAT(precio, 2)) AS precio
     , CONCAT('$', FORMAT(total, 2)) AS total
     , tipo 
  FROM servicio AS s 
 WHERE visto IS NULL
   AND nombre LIKE 'materna%'
;
```

Comment: Thank you, because it shows two results?                                                     1 2 MATERNA        0% $120.00 $120.00 1
2 99 PARACETAMOL 0% $10.00 $10.00 1

Comment: It seems like the question has morphed since this answer was offered.

Comment: Edit: UNION instead of UNION ALL (to avoid duplicate rows). Please check your SQL—I cannot reproduce your results. Please see this live demonstration: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8531a6/1/0)